# SQL Reporting Services: Why does my report shrink when it's emailed?

Tags: sql, email, reporting-services

I created a simple report and uploaded it to my report server. It looks correct on the report server, but when I set up an email subscription, the report is much narrower than it is supposed to be.

Here is what the report looks like in the designer. It looks similar when I view it on the report server: [http://img58.imageshack.us/img58/4893/designqj3.png]

Here is what the email looks like: [http://img58.imageshack.us/img58/9297/emailmy8.png]

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is fixed in SQL Server 2005 SP3 (it is part of cumulitive update package build 3161)

Problem issue described below.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/935399

Basically Full Outlook 2007 Client Uses MS Word HTML Rendering Engine (Which Makes Web Archive Report Looked Jacked Up).
NOTE: Web Outlook 2007 Client Uses IE HTML Rendering Engine (Which makes Web Archive Report Look Okay).

We have installed the patch on DB housing Reporting Services and it does fix the issue. Emails look all nice and fancy now.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that the screenshots show Outlook 2007. Perhaps you're not aware that Microsoft somewhat hobbled the HTML capabilities of Outlook in 2007, and now it uses the Word HTML engine, and not the more advanced Internet Explorer one? Might this explain the lacklustre appearance?

http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2007/01/10/microsoft-breaks-html-email-rendering-in-outlook/

Answer (score 1):

> I got around this problem by doing the
>   following:
>
> 1. Add a Page Header to the report
> 2. Add a line to the page header. Set the width of the line to the
>      desired page width.
> 3. Set the line colour to white (eg to hide the line)
>
> Hope this helps someone else,

Following on from girlC0d3r's solution, images aren't always guaranteed to be shown in an email.

A better solution to widening the report to prevent the content from wrapping is to have a long unbroken string of characters with no whitespace.

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

By giving the text the same color as the background of the email (e.g. white) they'll widen the report and be invisible to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything but my first guess is that the fonts are vastly different.  The designer has one font and the email is a flat, no-frills kind of thing with a simple font.  Without concrete examples, this is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a font thing, because the text is being wrapped a lot, and it looks about the same size.

The images show in my preview, but not in the final post. So, here are links to them.

Report in the designer: [http://img58.imageshack.us/img58/4893/designqj3.png]

Email result: [http://img58.imageshack.us/img58/9297/emailmy8.png]

Answer (score 0):

What report output format did you specify for the scheduled job?  It seems to me you used HTML, which will autoscale depending on the output browser (HTML adapts).

If having the same layout is important then use PDF as the output format.  Then, if the user wants to print the report you know exactly what it will look like and that it will fit nicely on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try a different format? pdf or xls maybe.  In my experience web archive looks goofy.  Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I'm using HTML. I would prefer to stick with that, because the users can just read it in their mail clients. PDF or XLS would require them to open an attachment.

I know that the HTML resizes itself to fit the browser, and that's a good thing. The problem I would like to fix is the wasted space - in the email client, the HTML shrinks too much.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this problem by doing the following:

1. Add a Page Header to the report
2. Add a line to the page header.  Set the width of the line to the desired page width.
3. Set the line colour to white (eg to hide the line)

Hope this helps someone else,

Answer (score 0):

girlC0d3r is along the right lines (no pun intended), but the line will likely be shrunk along with the rest of the HTML in the email.  A workaround I used yesterday was to create an image 1px high by 600px wide (or whatever), the same color as the background, and bring it into the report as an embedded image.  Place it above or below the body of your report.  This should force the intended width in the final email.  I used this technique successfully in a report yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue myself, exactly as portrayed in the OP's screenshots. The reports were beautifully rendered in nearly every format except for Web Archive. My trouble was the use of a rectangle containing each matrix that did not span the width of the report. Upon stretching it out through the remaining white space, the condensing behavior ceased. Hope that helps someone who doesn't have quick access to an SP upgrade!

Answer (score 0):

Where it is not an issue of running on old software that needs a patch...

The reason is the columns are different sizes is because the [MHTML Device Information Settings, 'OutlookCompat'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153991(v=sql.110)) is set to true

When creating an email subscription with MHTML format and open the report in Outlook, A [forum post by Microsoft employee Fanny Liu](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/19d3e4bd-43be-4856-8ee0-bfde5487105f/columns-change-widths-in-a-mhtml-subscription?forum=sqlreportingservices) says

> change the OutlookCompat configuration setting for the MHTML Rendering extension in rsreportserver.config. Set the value to: False.

As I was researching it appeared that this would impact more than just column size.  In my instance it was not that big of deal so I decided to leave well enough alone. It is correct in PDF and web, the email I send includes a link back to the report, if the client wants a pretty report they are going to want it in PDF, the email format is not expected to be printable.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue and this worked for me.

Go to --> Properties --> Report

Set InteractiveSize Width to 4.9in

Set Margins to 0 for Left, Right, Top, and Bottom

Set pageSize to Width to 4.9in