# Issue with font size of links in textbox of report

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

For some reason my subscription to a report gets emailed using the subscription service, the font sizes are increased only on text that has an underlying link for example:

[image]

However, when I run the report normally (just navigate to it using the browser), all is fine:

[image]

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Is the report coming as an attachment? if so, what kind of attachment?

Comment: @bluefeet its called a web archive

Comment: @bluefeet any recommendations on troubleshooting this?

Comment: @bluefeet i guess if this were a pivot question, u would respond ;)

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов Since it's a web archive, what happens if you look at it in a different browser?

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson thanks for the note! browser doesnt matter. they work in a browser without problems. but when i email it to outlook or gmail, the fonts are screwed

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов I disagree with your comment about the pivot question. I have been looking around online trying to find a possible reason for the issue. I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417032/sql-reporting-services-why-does-my-report-shrink-when-its-emailed) and [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1572269.aspx/1) but am still looking.

Comment: thanks so much! i know that you are the pivot god

Comment: @bluefeet u think its unsolvable?

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов, I do think it is unsolveable, or at lease not that I've seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me too. There is no fix

I just get mine either via pdf, excel or html not mhtml.

But html has it's own issues and is not recomended.

Comment: btw what is the difference between html and mhtml?

Comment: Mhtml is a web archive format, html is the original non archive

Comment: By definition it combines external links, etc.in one file